# How to bind IP:port in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm not able to bind a `IP:port` to container port in `AWS ECS` task definition. Such that on command line,

```
docker run "-p 172.17.42.1:14242:3000"
```

`172.17.42.1:14242` is `IP:port`. But in `AWS ECS` there are only two options, `hostPort` and `containerPort` and they take only integers not strings:

```
"portMappings": [
   {
      "hostPort": 14242,
      "containerPort": 3000
  }
]
```

So, how can I provide `IP:port` in task definition?

When I do (Without IP) `port:port` mapping, and after task creation I do:

```
aws ecs describe-tasks
```

it shows

> 0.0.0.0:14242:3000.

But I want specific IP not `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Is there a specific use-case where you require this functionality?  ECS may not be the right solution for your requirements, as it doesn't guarantee a specific container will deployed on specific hardware.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a supported feature as far as I'm aware, and it wouldn't make too much sense on ECS since the ip address of the host instance isn't known ahead of time.

ECS is designed to use all available EC2 instances in a "cluster" to deploy containers belonging to to a service/task.  One of ECS's core features is the flexibility to add/remove/update EC2 instances in the  cluster in an ad-hoc manner, and allow containers to be deployed on whichever cluster instances has available resources at the particular time when the task is launched.  This means there's no guarantee that you'll know the IP address ahead of time when you create the task definition, since you won't know for sure which EC2 instance it will be deployed on.

If you *really* have a strong use case where you must deploy a task/container on a specific EC2 instance and IP, then you could roll your own solution by interacting directly with the ECS agent. [1][2]

That said, I'd highly recommend re-examining your design and trying to implement it in a way that's host/ip agnostic.  For example, you could use Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) in the ECS "service" definition [3] to allow the containers to be reached through a fixed DNS hostname regardless of which IP they're hosted on.

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_agent.html

[2] https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent

[3] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-load-balancing.html